# infinite loop caused using fprintf

Tags: c

I am attempting to print a string of characters inputted by a user to a file (as characters), and stop printing when the end of the user input is reached. When I run the code, it appears that an infinite loop is created, and a very large amount of `▯` are printed to the file. I have no idea what is wrong.

Here is the code:

```
     printf("Please input a character string, no spaces: \n\n");
     scanf("%c", &c);  //assigns user input to c var
     while ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) { //check char is an integer
         fprintf(f, "%c", &c);

         if (c == 0x0A) {
             fprintf(f, "\n\n");
             fclose(f);
         }
     }
```

Here is an image of the output file: [File1.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YazGo.png)

Comment: Tell us, which line in the loop changes the value of `c`? If you can answer that then you will have answered your own question.

Comment: Agree with @kaylum and you also printing the address of variable c as a character.

Comment: Note that the text in the printed message is misleading: `%c` format reads a single character, not a string of any sort.  Also, given that only digits can enter the loop, there's no way that `c` can equal `0x0A` (which would be better written `'\n'`) inside the loop.  That's probably just as well; the print and close would lead to disaster if the `if` block was ever entered a second time.  You should add a `break;` after the `fclose()`, or perhaps a `return`.

Comment: Also, `fprintf` with a format of `%c` will want a `char` argument, and not a `char*` (assuming `c` is a `char`).

Answer (score 1):

First, learn how to read a string the reliable, simple way. Forget `scanf` in almost all cases when it comes to reading strings and learn to use `fgets`. Second, your fundamental problem is you're reading a single character and then looping endlessly on that one character. You did not read a string, and you never examine or output more than the first character they entered.

Try something like this:

```
char str[129];
printf("Please input a character string, no spaces: \n\n");
fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
size_t len = strlen(str);
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    char c = str[i];
    if(c == 0x0A)
        break;

    if (c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) //check char is an integer
        fprintf(f, "%c", c);
}
fprintf(f, "\n\n");
fclose(f);
```

I didn't add any error checking. You need to make sure `fgets` actually succeeded, at a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop because you do not modify the `c` variable inside the `while` loop, so the condition always computes to the same value...

Furthermore, you do not print the character: you pass the **address** of `c` instead of its **value**. This invokes undefined behavior as an address is not appropriate for a `%c` conversion specifier.

Here is a corrected version:

```
    printf("Please input a character string, no spaces:\n\n");
    c = 0;
    while (scanf("%c", &c) == 1 && (c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) {
        fprintf(f, "%c", c);
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        fprintf(f, "\n\n");
        fclose(f);
    }
```

Note however that you do not store the characters read and you do not `fclose()` the file if a newline is not read.  Your logic seems broken. It would be simpler to read a full line with `fgets()` and scan the input for validation and further processing.

```
    char line[80];
    if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        int digits = strspn(line, "0123456789");
        if (digits > 0 && line[digits] == '\n') {
            fprintf(f, "%.*s", digits, line);  // output the digits
            // handle the value read?
        } else {
            // handle incorrect input
        }
    } else {
        // handle premature end of file
    }
    fclose(f);
```